# div position relative to parent height

Tags: javascript, height, vertical-alignment

I have a '#Index-BG' with 80% of window.innerHeight. Now I need this child '#Verticais-R' which is rotated CW 90º to be vertical align center relatively to the 80% of parent's height.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var div=document.getElementById('Verticais-R'); 
div.setAttribute('style', '-ms-transform-origin: center center; position:absolute; top:'+ (document.getElementById('Index-BG').style.clientHeight-500) *0.5+'px; right:+35px;') ;
```

any tips? I think the problem here is that it's not recognising parent's height?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `.offsetHeight` instead of a `.clientHeight`. Offset dimensions are the calculated data by the browser.